# Adding text to posters with RMagick and Carrierwave. uninitialized constant PhotoUploader::Draw

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, carrierwave, rmagick

I am trying to do image manipulation as process to add some text to my app.
The effect I'm looking for is : adding text to image, after saving.
The problem I'm dealing here is I get error: uninitialized constant PhotoUploader::Draw.

## photo_uploader.rb

```
process :poster

def poster
 manipulate! do |source|
  txt = Draw.new
  txt.family
  txt.pointsize = 12
  txt.gravity = Magick::SouthGravity
  txt.stroke = "#000000"
  title = Demot.last.title
  source = source.resize_to_fill(400, 400).border(10, 10, "black")
  source.annotate(txt, 0, 0, 0, 40, title)

end
```

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to

```
txt = Magick::Draw.new
```